# Alpine container error /bin/sh upload.sh not found even after installing bash

Tags: bash, docker, alpine-linux

I am facing an error when attempting to run a bash script inside an alpine container :

```
/bin/sh: upload.sh: not found
```

This is happening ***despite that I have already installed bash*** as in the Dockerfile below :

```
# bash on alpine

FROM quay.io/bashell/alpine:latest
WORKDIR /tmp

# make sure the package repository is up to date
RUN apk update \
 && apk upgrade \
 && apk add bash \
 && rm -rf /var/cache/*/* \
 && echo "" > /root/.ash_history

# change default shell from ash to bash
RUN sed -i -e "s/bin\/ash/bin\/bash/" /etc/passwd

ENV LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8

# copy in upload.sh
COPY upload.sh .
RUN chmod +x upload.sh
RUN apk update && apk add curl git
RUN curl -LO https://storage.googleapis.com/kubernetes-release/release/v1.15.1/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
RUN chmod u+x kubectl && mv kubectl /bin/kubectl
```

The script upload.sh :

```
#!/bin/bash
touch myfile.txt
FILE=$(pwd)
echo "File is available at $FILE/myfile.txt
```

"

Output of ls -la :

```
 /tmp # ls -la
total 16
drwxrwxrwt    1 root     root          4096 Sep 19 14:40 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Sep 20 10:14 ..
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root            88 Sep 19 14:33 upload.sh
```

What I have tried :

1. Run and exec into the container

   /tmp # which bash
   /bin/bash
2. Checked the formatting for upload.sh

Line endings is correct - LF

Encoding is correct  - UTF-8

3. Tried using /bin/sh in the script (without and with bash installed) - still getting the same error
4. Tried using /bin/ash in the script (without and with bash installed) - still getting the same error

**UPDATE:**

I have found that when I exec into the container and run the script as :

```
sh upload
```

it executes successfully.

The actual use-case is to run the Docker container (**and hence the script**) in a K8S environment with the following deployment configuration (Is this correct?) :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: alpine
  namespace: labs
spec:
  serviceAccountName: alpine
  containers:
  - image: myuser/alpine-kubectl
    volumeMounts:
            - name: datadir
              mountPath: /tmp
    command:
      - sh
      - "-c"
      - "./upload.sh && sleep 100000000"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: alpine
    
  restartPolicy: Always
  volumes:
        - name: datadir
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: alpine
```

Is this correct or I should handle the issue at the time I build the Dockerfile?

Comment: have you confirmed the file is on the system where you try to run it at?

Comment: yes I can exec into the running container and do ls in the /tmp path. The file is indeed there

Comment: have you tried running the commands one by one to test they work?

Comment: @Randommm  "which bash" shows that  bash  is being installed successfullly . chmod +x upload.sh is also executing successfully when building the Docker image

Comment: I mean the commands in the file

Comment: Not yet. I am not sure what you mean , unless it means testing the script on another environment. Yes I have tested the script on AWS Cloud9 instance

Comment: What is your image's `CMD`?  How are you trying to run this script?  Does putting it somewhere other than `/tmp` help?

Comment: @DavidMaze its not directory issue. I have copied the script to /home same error. But then I have just found out if I do "sh upload.sh" the script is executing, in all directories

Comment: How do run that file? It seems that the shell is looking the file based on the `$PATH` environment. Try `set PATH="$PATH:."`

Comment: Don't put `.` in `$PATH` (outside of a container this can represent a real security problem, but even ignoring the security issues it can also lead to unexpected behavior), but do run the file using a fully qualified path: either `./upload.sh` or `/tmp/upload.sh`

Comment: @larsks  check the question. I have updated it accordingly